# Why is Swift multithreading much less efficient when using functions in imported modules?

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency

I am going to leave out a lot of 'irrelevant' details here to help people concentrate on the actual question.

I have a Swift project which involves a great deal of calculations (numerical integration and multi parameter best fit etc). To speed things up I am aiming to use concurrent processing.

Using XCTest classes, I have discovered that with my closure calling a function defined within my module, if I use DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform with a single iteration, it takes time t. When repeated with 5 iterations, it runs about 5% slower (I am happy with that).

NB the function is a static function on a struct (my collection of calculus routines).

However, if I put the function in a separate module and import this, repeating the test with 1 iteration takes a similar time t. But now when I try it with 5 iterations, the call takes twice as long (105% slower in fact).

Swift version: 4.2.1
OS: macOS 10.14.3
Xcode 10.1
Processor: 6 core Core i7 (Mac mini 2018)

All 'objects' are structs and value types used everywhere, apart from the function reference.

Quick summary again: using **DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform()**, compared to the baseline time for 1 iteration of a *same-module* defined function, **5 iterations is 5% slower**. However when doing the same process using a function which has been defined in an *imported module*, baseline time remains unchanged for 1 iteration but **5 iterations is 105% slower**.

Can anyone explain why this happens, and hopefully suggest a way of avoiding this slowdown while keeping my collection in an importable module?

Feel free to ask questions if you need more information.

Comment: New development which invalidates my initial question. Rather than moving my calculation code to the testing module, I've moved my test to the calculation module. Really strangely the 5 iterations now runs 200% slower than a single iteration. So now I'll be concentrating on figuring out why that is.

Comment: Possibly the time difference is due to inlining. When the computation functions lived in the same module, the compiler was able to inline some of the function calls. This changed when you moved the code to a different module.

Comment: Can't speak with confidence, but I would be surprised if that was the case, since the single thread version was just as fast in the module as it was in main code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. No clue what the cause was.

Removed my project, created a fresh one, imported the files back in to it, included it in the workspace.

Now 5 concurrent threads process in only 10% longer than a single thread (doing 5x the amount of work). Would still love to know what caused the issue, and would be good if the efficiency drop was only 5% as had been in the earlier mentioned case.

But for this improvement just from starting a fresh project, I'm not going to quibble!